# disable a textarea with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to disable a textarea from handling a keyboard event when ever a user presses the enter key of the keyboard when the textarea is empty using angularjs. I have been able to disable the submit button when the textarea is empty but I am trying to disable the textarea when from enter event when the textarea is empty.

This is my attempt:

```
<div class="descriptionarea">
    <textarea ng-model="trackTxt" id="input" ></textarea>
    <span class="buttonfortxtarea">
    <button ng-disabled="!trackTxt" class= "btn btn-mini description_submit" id="new-chat-button">Submit</button></span>
    </div>
```

When I hit enter from my textarea it triggers event using the following code

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) { // enter key press
            send();
        }
    });
```

The above code works whether the textarea is empty or not.

EDITTED:

In my app.js of angularjs

```
app.controller('TodoCtrl',function($scope){

    //handle javascript enter event on key up
   // function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.trackTxt;
    $scope.send = function($event){
        alert('TEST');
  }

  $scope.isEmpty = function(param){
    return param.trim().length === 0;
  }
//}

});
```

In jsp file

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
     <textarea ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && !isEmpty(trackTxt) && send($event)" ng-model="trackTxt" id="input" ></textarea>
    <span class="buttonfortxtarea">
    <button ng-disabled="!trackTxt" ng-click="send($event)" class= "btn btn-mini description_submit" id="new-chat-button">Submit</button></span>
  </div></div>
```

Please how can I use angularjs to prevent the enter event from happening when ever the text-area is empty.

Comment: by enter event, do you mean form submit event?

Comment: Waht do you want to achieve by doing such disabling of event which disable some events and so ...?

Comment: Ok, may be do you want to disable submit button when there is no text in textarea haven't take in account spaces and enters?

Comment: If the textarea is blank or has no text disable it from triggering the enter keyboard using angular

Comment: I dont want the textarea to send an empty text using angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-keyup for attaching an function on enter key press,

```
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && functionToCall()"
```

Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26784/),

Thanks

Comment: This way you can use angular directive **ng-keyup** for attaching key up event listener handler.

Comment: Check this update **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26786/)** as this contains all the requirement you mention , Sorry i missed one on my previous one, Thanks, Hope this helps.

Comment: I am having some issues implementing this in my project

Comment: can you share how you are implementing?

Comment: which angular version you are using

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Any error your getting in developer tools?Please share

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js use this link

Comment: it seems your angular js source is having some issues.

Comment: use updated version of angular as 1.0.3 does not have ng-keypress for better clearity please check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/1107/).

Comment: I hope this fix the problem

Comment: 1.2.14 version or higher have ng-keypress

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.14/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if it's empty...

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13 && $(this).val() != "") { // enter key press
            send();
        }
});
```

This also may work:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length <= 0) { // enter key press
            send();
        }
});
```

To prevent the default enter use [preventDefault() Event Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length <= 0) { // enter key press
            e.preventDefault(); //This avoid the enter...
        }
});
```

How about the sendChat()...

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length <= 0) { // enter key press
            e.preventDefault(); //This avoid the enter...
        }
        else if(code == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
            sendChat();
        }
});
```

Comment: This prevents enter event of the keyboard

Comment: On hitting the enter keyboard, nothing happens even when there is text in the textarea

Comment: I want the enter key of the keyboard to happen only when there is text in the textarea

Comment: @user6731422 `document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) { var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) { e.preventDefault(); } });` this one (the last one, should be doing exactly that...

Comment: what about this method sendChat();

Comment: I believe that kind of stuff you should be able to figure them out yourself if you work as a programmer, but well I edited my answer to include it...

Comment: if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length <= 0) { // enter key press

Comment: (index):305 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined